# UISearch not showing results

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm querying from parse and I when I try to search using the search bar it returns with "no results." I'm trying to figure out what I did wrong showing the objects because it does show in the NSLog that it has found objects.

My viewDidLoad:

```
   - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;

    self.searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:self.searchBar contentsController:self];

    self.searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    self.searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray array];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

The Retrieving for the Table View:

```
   -(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm {

    [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"New"];
    [query whereKeyExists:@"title"]; //this is based on whatever query you are trying to accomplish
    [query whereKey:@"title" containsString:searchTerm];

    NSArray *results  = [query findObjects];

    NSLog(@"%u", results.count);

    [self.searchResults addObjectsFromArray:results];
}
```

Finally, The tableview cell that doesn't want to work:

```
   -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {

           static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    PFObject * testObject = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [testObject objectForKey:@"title"];

    return cell;
    }
```

Then:

```
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterResults:searchString];
    return YES;
}
```

Then to load from Parse to UTTableview:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithClassName:@"New"];
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        // The className to query on
        self.ClassName = @"New";

        //self.textKey = @"title";

        // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
        // self.keyToDisplay = @"text";

        // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
        self.pullToRefreshEnabled = NO;

        // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
        self.paginationEnabled = YES;

        self.loadingViewEnabled = NO;

        // The number of objects to show per page
        self.objectsPerPage = 50;
    }
    return self;

}
```

Comment: `searchResults` is a MutableArray and `result` is a simple array. 
You'll need to do this for making it Mutable.
`self.searchResults = [results mutableCopy];`

Comment: Its a method that converts a immutable object into mutable one.

Comment: `self.searchResults = result;` should be giving you a warning because the type of both variables are not the same... ie. `mutableArray = immutableArray` so to get it correctly done you have to convert your immutable to mutable

Comment: It still didn't work. I do have a warning saying on this line "self.searchResults = result;"and the warning says its a  "incompatible pointer" @AhmedZ.

Comment: How would I fix that? @AhmedZ.

Comment: Yes thats what em trying to say.. since both sides datatype dont match thats why its giving a warning..

Comment: you tried replacing `self.searchResults = result;` with `self.searchResults = [result mutableCopy];`?

Comment: Yes I have. The warning is now gone but still no results. @AhmedZ.

Comment: No I have not. Where would I put that? @iOSCoder

Comment: Yes add `[tableview reloadData];` after `self.searchResults = [result mutableCopy];`

Comment: Its just giving me and error. @AhmedZ.

Comment: what error is it giving??

Comment: For some reason its saying "tableview" doesn't exist!? @AhmedZ.

Comment: whats your tableView's name?\

Comment: I dont have one named. I thought that wasnt need when using parse APIs@AhmedZ.

Comment: then how did you bind the tableview in xib file or storyboard...?

Comment: Just by adding the class name in the StoryBoard. Was I suppose to do something else? @AhmedZ.

Comment: have you ever implemented a tableView before..?

Comment: Not when using parse. Check this code out and tell me if this looks better @AhmedZ.

Comment: You have to implement the tableView same way as you do without parse.. just when you get the data from parse, call tableview's reloadData and then you'll get the data shown in the tableview

Comment: Where would i add it in my new code? Its taking away the search bar when i add that @AhmedZ.

Comment: you'll need to add a SearchBar to the tableview..

Comment: Okay added it still no results. @AhmedZ.

Comment: why have you done this .. ` if (tableView == self.tableView) {
        //if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        return self.objects.count;

    } else {

        return self.searchResults.count;

    }
`

Comment: in this method.. `-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {`

Comment: change the code in `numberOfRowsInSection` to just `return self.searchResults.count;`

Comment: I dont remember i got that from a source code. I git rid of it didnt change it

Comment: Okay still nothing @AhmedZ.

Comment: Sorry dude cant understand what you are doing wrong.... it should be working fine now.. look around.. play with it.. try some different code combinations..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use another way where you can take the help of the search bar delegate method.

e.g - Include `UISearchBarDelegate` in your header file and also -

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchSong;
```

Now in your .m file

```
- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    temp = [self searchSongsData:self.searchSong.text from:`YourArray`];
} 

+ (NSMutableArray *) searchSongsData:(NSString *)searchtext from:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    NSMutableArray *arrayToBeReturned = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *temp = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:array];

    NSString *textToBeSearch = [searchtext lowercaseString];

    SongsMoviesData *songs;

    for(int i = 0; i<temp.count; i++)
    {
        songs = [temp objectAtIndex:i];

        NSString *string1 = [songs.song_title lowercaseString];
        NSString *string2 = [songs.moview_name lowercaseString];
        NSString *string3 = [songs.singer_name lowercaseString];


    if ([string1 rangeOfString:textToBeSearch].location != NSNotFound ||[string2 rangeOfString:textToBeSearch].location != NSNotFound || [string3 rangeOfString:textToBeSearch].location != NSNotFound)
    {
       // NSLog(@"%@", songs.moview_name);
        [arrayToBeReturned addObject:songs];
    }
}

return arrayToBeReturned;
```

}

and like this you save this array in your `search results`.

Comment: Did you define the `searchResults` in your header file like this -      @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

Comment: I did that let me edit my code this might look better to you.

Comment: Please include a line in your viewDidLoad where you allocate memory to  the mutableArray `searchResults`.

Comment: Like this  self.searchResults = mutableArray; ?

Comment: self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];                   Or replace your line in viewDidLoad with              self.searchResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray: array];(If you have anything named array)

Comment: In your function ` -(void)filterResults:(NSString *)searchTerm` put a breakpoint after the point where u=you get `results` and check does it have anything in it.?

Comment: Okay I added the breakpoint and It did stop my program and put a green line over   [self.searchResults removeAllObjects];

Comment: In my NSLog it says I'm receiving objects

Comment: what was the count of `results` array?? did you check??

Comment: when i type "s" its 1 when i type "t" i get 2 thats In my NSLog